# Count commits on Github api

Tags: api, github

is-it possible to retrieve the number of commits for a particular user with Github API v3 ?

The only way I've found is to list all commits and increment a counter... Is there a simpler way please ? Thank you.

Comment: I have no answer using the API that is any cleaner, though you could clone the repo and use `git shortlog -s -n` (or `git shortlog -s -n | ack name`).

Comment: Thank you Chris, but the ideal would be to do with the api.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Repository Statistics](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics) API documentation. Specifically, the [contributors](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#contributors) endpoint would be useful to you.

You can get a list of contributors along with addition, deletion, and commit statistics for a given repository.

I'm not aware of an API endpoint that would give you commit statistics for a user's activity across all repositories.